# How to obtain the values from each row at given position in pytorch?

Tags: python, pytorch

How to obtain the values from a 2-d torch array based on 1-d array containing the positions at each row:

for example:

```
a = torch.randn((5,5))
>>> a
tensor([[ 0.0740, -0.3129,  0.7814, -0.0519,  1.3503],
        [ 1.1985,  0.2098, -0.0326,  0.3922,  0.5037],
        [-1.4334,  1.4047, -0.6607, -1.8024, -0.0088],
        [ 1.2116,  0.5928,  1.4041,  1.0494, -0.1146],
        [ 0.4173,  1.0482,  0.5244, -2.1767,  0.5264]])

b = torch.randint(0,5, (5,))
>>> b
tensor([1, 0, 1, 3, 2])
```

I wanted to get the elements of tensor `a` at the position given by tensor `b`

For example:

```
desired output:
tensor([-0.3129,
        1.1985,
        1.4047,
        1.0494,
        0.5244])
```

Here, each element in a given position by tensor `b` is chosen row-wise.

I have tried:

```
for index in range(b.size(-1)):
    val = torch.cat((val,a[index,b[index]].view(1,-1)), dim=0) if val is not None else a[index,b[index]].view(1,-1)


>>> val
tensor([[-0.3129],
        [ 1.1985],
        [ 1.4047],
        [ 1.0494],
        [ 0.5244]])
```

However, is there a tensor indexing way to do it?
I tried couple of solutions using tensor indexing, but none of them worked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`torch.gather`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.gather.html#torch-gather)

```py
>>> a.gather(1, b.unsqueeze(1))
tensor([[-0.3129],
        [ 1.1985],
        [ 1.4047],
        [ 1.0494],
        [ 0.5244]])
```

Or

```py
>>> a[range(len(a)), b].unsqueeze(1)
tensor([[-0.3129],
        [ 1.1985],
        [ 1.4047],
        [ 1.0494],
        [ 0.5244]])
```